# While updating date compare date with another field to update field

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a button and when a user clicks it, the button sets the `due_date` in the database. Then I have another button that when it's clicked it sets the `date_finished` in the database.

I have one more field that needs to be completed and then the finished button is clicked. I am trying to figure out how to compare the `date_finished` to the `date_due` such that if the date is after the `date_due`(the next day) I want to update my `Late` field with a 'Y' or if the `date_finished` was on time or equal to the same day update my `Late` field with an 'N'.

I can not figure out how to compare the dates though in the same query.

[image]

```
<cfquery name="workComplete">
        UPDATE dbo.Work 
        SET date_finished = getDate(),
              <cfif date_finished > due_date>
                Late = <cfqueryparam value="Y" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
              <cfelse>
                Late = <cfqueryparam value="N" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
              </cfif>
        WHERE id = <cfqueryparam value="11" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">,          
    </cfquery>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use a `CASE` statement to compare based on database values

```
    <cfquery name="workComplete">
      UPDATE dbo.Work 
      SET date_finished = getDate(),
      Late = CASE WHEN date_finished > due_date THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
      WHERE id = <cfqueryparam value="11" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">,          
    </cfquery>
```

If date_finished is a value in ColdFusion you can output it at a ColdFusion value as well

```
    <cfquery name="workComplete">
      UPDATE dbo.Work 
      SET date_finished = getDate(),
      Late = CASE WHEN #form.date_finished# > due_date THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
      WHERE id = <cfqueryparam value="11" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">,          
    </cfquery>
```

Comment: is there a way to take the time portion out?

Comment: from what? You can use ColdFusion `dateFormat()` to format a timestamp to just a date

Comment: well im trying to compare both of those fields but only the dates and its taking the time into consideration also

Comment: I added the pic above

Comment: technically it should have an N since its the same date

Comment: but since the time is greater its still inserting a Y

Comment: I just googled I think this might be the answer: SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())

Comment: yep it needed CONVERT(date, getdate()),

Comment: (Edit) Which value has the date (only) and which one has the date and time?

Comment: date_finished had both date and time

Comment: Then use cfqueryparam with cf_sql_date. Using that cfsqltype truncates the time value, so the query only compares dates. Plus it protects against sql injection. ie `... CASE WHEN <cfqueryparam value="#form.date_finished#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"> due_date .... `.